# How to create a time series out of a pandas dataframe of events with a start time and end time for each row

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

What I want to return is the maximum **active** value at a current time, with a new row for every time the maximum changes. (Where active means the event has started but not yet ended) For example, this table:

| start_time | end_time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12:00 | (null) | 5 |
| 12:35 | 13:00 | 11 |
| 12:45 | 12:55 | 21 |

should give this:

| time | current max value |
| --- | --- |
| 12:00 | 5 |
| 12:35 | 11 |
| 12:45 | 21 |
| 12:55 | 11 |
| 13:00 | 5 |

A small detail is that some end times are null meaning the event was active indefinitely. Would anyone know how to tackle this?

Comment: Judging by the example you provided you just need to drop the end_time column. Will df.drop(labels = ['end_time'], axis=1) work? If you need to conver start_time to datetime object use df.start_time = pd.to_datetime(df.start_time)

Comment: it looks like you move data from `end_time` to `start_time`. You could create two DataFrames - one with `start_time, value`, second with `end_time, value` (and rename column `end_time` into `start_time`, and remove rows with `null`) and later concatenate both dataframes - `result = pd.concat([df1, df2])`

Comment: YKY no that wouldn't work, I need the end time, as I don't want the max to take into account events that have already ended. Look at the example - if I drop the end time the value wouldn't go back to 11 from 21 at 12:55

Comment: furas I'm not sure you understand the problem, when a value reaches its end time it should no longer be the max as it is no longer 'active'. End times are therefore not the same as start times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it gives you the desired output.

**Creating Data frame:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import time

Idata= {'Start' : [pd.Timestamp(pd.Timestamp(2022, 1, 1, 12)),pd.Timestamp(pd.Timestamp(2022, 1, 1, 12 ,35)),pd.Timestamp(pd.Timestamp(2022, 1, 1, 12,45))] , 'End' : [np.nan,pd.Timestamp(pd.Timestamp(2022, 1, 1, 13)),pd.Timestamp(pd.Timestamp(2022, 1, 1, 12,55))], 'Value' : [5,11,21]}

df=pd.DataFrame(Idata)
df=df.fillna(pd.Timestamp(pd.Timestamp(2022, 1, 1, 23,59,59))).sort_values(by="Start",ascending=[True],axis=0)
df['Start'] = [dt.datetime.time(d) for d in df['Start']]
df['End'] = [dt.datetime.time(d) for d in df['End']]
```

**Operation Code :**

```
df1=df[["Start","Value"]]
df2=df[["End","Value"]].copy()
df2.rename({"End":"Start"},inplace=True,axis=1)
df3=pd.concat([df1,df2]).reset_index(drop=True)

for i in range(len(df3)):
    a=[0]
    for j in range(len(df)):
        if df3.loc[i,'Start'] >= df.loc[j,'Start']:
            if df3.loc[i,'Start'] < df.loc[j,'End']:
                a.append(df['Value'][j])
    df3.loc[i,'Value']=max(a)
df3=df3.sort_values(by="Start",ascending=[True],axis=0)
df3=df3[df3['Start']!=dt.datetime.time(pd.Timestamp(2022, 1, 1, 23,59,59))]
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: @Tadgh Kelly , Does this answer your query?